# Retrieving Interest/Page information out of facebook

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Im wondering if there is anyway to interogate facebook data on user interests. i.e. Retrieve the following data sets:

1. What are the most like interests/Pages on facebook?
2. Retreive the current users facebook interest and also their friends interests?

Really want to know if we can get facebook global interest/like data and than also if the user connects their facebook account to the site than we can also retrieve their interest data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to implement something like http://www.socialbakers.com/ ?
To get 1) you'd have to periodically poll the API for the public fan count of a known set of page IDs to see the current fan counts ( i think this is what socialbakers do)

To get 2, get the `user_likes` and `friend_likes` [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) from your users and access the `/likes` connection of the users whose likes you want to read

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retrieve user interests from facebook. You just need to include the user_interests permission required in your jsp page.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
If you are using spring social you can generate your own url for /me/interests:

```java
URIBuilder uriBuilder1 = URIBuilder.fromUri(facebook.GRAPH_API_URL + "me" +"/interests");
String s = facebook.restOperations().getForObject(uriBuilder1.build(), String.class);
```